# Image is not appearing in the print preview chrome

Tags: javascript

While we want print the HTML page then image is not appearing in print preview, I tried with multiple area but not generate the outoput. Right Now in print preview it is not showing the correct one. It is very request everyone, Please help for this issue.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pat id="Main_Window">
    <title>Main Window</title>
    <body>
        <p>The main console screen includes nine panels or areas, which are shown and described below.</p>
        <p><image width="600" href="../MiVBC_Graphics1/MainWindow_CloudlinkChat.bmp" placement="break"/></p>
        <p>Content here</p>
        <p>Content here</p>
        <p>Content here</p>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </body>
</pat>
```

**Java Script code:**

```
function printIframe(url, height) {
                var heading_one = window.iframeHeight.heading
                var test = window.iframeHeight.maindivcontent
                console.log(test)
                console.log("fhghfjghdfjghfdg")
                var proxyIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                body.appendChild(proxyIframe);
                proxyIframe.style.width = '100%';
                proxyIframe.style.height = '100%';
                proxyIframe.style.display = 'none';
                var contentWindow = proxyIframe.contentWindow;
                contentWindow.document.open();
                var is_chrome = Boolean(contentWindow.chrome);
                contentWindow.document.write(test)
                contentWindow.document.write('<iframe onload="print();" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>');
                contentWindow.document.close(); 
                if (is_chrome) {
                    contentWindow.onload = function() { 
                    };
                }
                else {contentWindow.document.write('<iframe onload="print();" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>');
    contentWindow.document.close(); }return true;}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Does it still show up for you outside of print mode? Because when I test your code it doesn't. However, it works when you change the **img href** to **src**:

```
<p><image width="600" src="../MiVBC_Graphics1/MainWindow_CloudlinkChat.bmp" placement="break"/></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, It is working fine while I used setTimeout(function()

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timeout to give the browser some time to render the images.
Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    contentWindow.print();
    contentWindow.close();
}, 250);
```

And you also need to used src instead of href